# Vakil 11.1.D: Fibers of integral morphisms have dimension 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm working through Ravi Vakil's "Rising Sea" notes for an independent study, and I'm working on Exercise 11.1.D in the most recent version of the notes.

I'm not sure I understand his hint for this exercise. He takes a $k$-algebra $A$ that is an integral extension of $k$, and mods $A$ out by a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, and relabels the result as $A$ in order to make $A$ an integral domain, and then proves that $A$ is a field so that $\dim A = 0$.

How is he able to do this? Wouldn't modding out $A$ by a prime ideal increase the dimension of the original $A$ by one?

Comment: If $A\to B$ is a surjective map of commutative rings, $\dim B\leq \dim A$.

Comment: If $A$ isn't an integral domain, then $\mathrm{Spec}$ $A$ is either reducible or non-reduced.  Picture $A = k \oplus k$ or $A = k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$.  Modding out by a prime ideal will (respectively) pick out one of the irreducible components or remove the "fuzz" here; it won't decrease the dimension.

Comment: And he's just modding out by $\mathfrak p$ to get a contradiction.  You can run through the rest of the argument with the letter $A$ replaced by $A/\mathfrak{p}$ and it should make more sense.

Comment: Thank you. In the case where $A$ is reducible, you can pick out a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ where $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is the irreducible component of $A$ of highest dimension, which has the same dimension as $A$. In the case where $A$ is non-reduced, you can choose $\mathfrak{p}$ to be $\mathfrak{N}(A)$, and $A/\mathfrak{p}$ will have the same dimension as $A$.